# In videojs, how to unbind keyboard shortcuts set by videojs?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js, shortcut

I am building my own media player based on videojs by modifying the source code. What I am trying to do now is to bind my own keyboard shortcuts, but apparently videojs has set some shortcuts in advance. In order to bind my own keyboard shortcuts, I need to remove the default shortcuts set in videojs.

How to unbind/remove keyboard shortcuts set by videojs?

Answer (score 0):

In the code I found this:

```
  ClickableComponent.prototype.handleKeyPress = function handleKeyPress(event) {
    // Support Space (32) or Enter (13) key operation to fire a click event
    if (event.which === 32 || event.which === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.handleClick(event);
    } else if (_Component.prototype.handleKeyPress) {
      _Component.prototype.handleKeyPress.call(this, event); // Pass keypress handling up for unsupported keys
    }
  };
```

I'm simply searching for 32 witch is the keycode from space. The player use only two shortcuts for enter and space. So I commended the lines to this:

```
  ClickableComponent.prototype.handleKeyPress = function handleKeyPress(event) {
    // Support Space (32) or Enter (13) key operation to fire a click event
    if (event.which === 32 || event.which === 13) {
      //event.preventDefault();
      //this.handleClick(event);
    } else if (_Component.prototype.handleKeyPress) {
      //_Component.prototype.handleKeyPress.call(this, event); // Pass keypress handling up for unsupported keys
    }
  };
```

The only problem is when you click the fullscreen icon and press the spacebar it will exit the fullscreen mode. But the rest is removed. Like play/paused, mute and Captions. I hope it help! And sorry for my bad english.

Edit:
I solved the problem by this code after the video.js import:

```
$('.vjs-fullscreen-control').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById('example_video1').focus();
    },20);
});
```